# identifications: sanity check

Tags: general-topology

A continuous surjective map $p: X \to Y$ is called identification if $O$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$. For surjective maps it is true that $f(f^{-1}(O)) = O$ for any set $O$. Can one define identification equivalently as follows?

A continuous surjective map $p: X \to Y$ is called identification if $O$ is open in $X$ if and only if $f(O)$ is open in $Y$?

Comment: No, a continuous surjections is an identification iff it sends *saturated* open sets to open sets.

Comment: Note that this property is very strong. For example, for a constant map $f:X\to Y, f(x)=c$ for all $x\in X$, where $\{c\}$ is open is $Y$, it means that $X$ has the discrete topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the latter would be an open map. All open (surjective) maps are identifications, but not vice versa. The criterion is that for all *saturated* open sets $O\subset X$ (that is, $O = f^{-1}(f(O))$), the image $f(O)$ be open.

P.S.: the more common term for identifications is, as far as I'm aware, "quotient map".

Comment: I’d say rather that *quotient map* is the more general term, *identification map* being used primarily when one specifically wants to think of the quotient space as resulting from an identification.

Comment: I have also seen *quotient map* used specifically to denote a natural quotient map, i.e. one mapping points to the corresponding equivalence classes.